# Sharing GoogleMaps object between two activities

Tags: android, gis, android-maps-v2

I have both A and B activities.

A uses GoogleMaps for adding markers, B to adding lines.

But A and B opens their own map.

How can i use same map on both activities? I don't want to pass marker and line datas again and again for every load.

Comment: Are you using Fragments? Did you try using a MapFragment? I'm not sure, but it might work with different Activities

Comment: Im using that for every activity's ui xml i used maps:
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/haritafragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
But none fragment object in classes. Just GoogleMap object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus to pass any complex object around in Android.

Example passing the map from one Activity to another:

Add your GoogleMap on the EventBus:

```
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(googleMap);
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SomeActivity.class));
```

Anywhere in SomeActivity:

```
GoogleMap googleMap = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(GoogleMap.class);
```

This examle is just to show that it works across Activities, you can call `getStickyEvent` to get your map anywhere in your code.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.greenrobot.event.EventBus

Comment: You need to add the jar to `libs` folder of your project, the jar can be found here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.greenrobot%22%20AND%20a%3A%22eventbus%22

Comment: error solved but the sticky map has no markers or another attributes. It shows world map. Eventbus doesn't work on this i think.

Comment: Well, you need to somehow apply the map to the MapFragment, otherwise the map will just show a new, default, map. Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: My code is too messy, can you give me a little example?

Comment: Ok, so now I inspected my code, and it seems you might have to do more work, such as keeping a record of all the markers etc added to the map and apply these when switching to the next Activity. In my case, I was in a single Activity environment, only changing fragments. So I was keeping a reference to one instance of MapFragment, which keeps referencing the same GoogleMap object. When creating a new Map it seems you cannot just give it a GoogleMap object from what I found.

Comment: EventBus can still be helpful though, cause you can create a object that can do all the work, say, GoogleMapHelper or something, and let it 'record' all the operations done to the GoogleMap object. Then when moving to Activity B, you can pass your GoogleMapHelper and call something like 'applyChanges(googleMap)', to add markers, drawings, whatever.. to the map.

Comment: GoogleMapHelper thing is the same method as now im using. Adding attributes to new map. I want get exact object. I think i should try your fragment thing, do it without changing activity. Thanks by the way.

Comment: No problem. It took me a while to figure out, but now I can handle orientation and tab switching (which either shows the fragment or not depending on phone or tablet) and it is instantly ready with all my markers after initial load.